# Can we do graceful error handling with ErrorBoundary?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to understand how are we suppose to use ErrorBoundary as central error handling point. There are different kinds of exceptions that could be handled by ErrorBoundary, and not to show same generic message that something went wrong.

if we wrap @Body with CustomErrorBoundary, we will caught any exception that we did not handle in our code. This is also true for 401 - Not authorized. We do not want to check for 401 on each API call, that would be a lot of repeating code. So:

```
protected override Task OnErrorAsync(Exception exception)
{
    if (exception is HttpRequestException requestException)
    {
        if (requestException.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            // what to do to swallow exception and navigate to some route?
            // NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/notauthorized");
        }
    }
}
```

Whatever I write in OnErrorAsync, Blazor will show CustomErrorBoundary's ErrorContent. In ErrorContent we usually put some message like: Oops, something went wrong, etc... And that is what I want to avoid, since in this case I know what went wrong, and navigate to /notauthorized, which is handled by my custom NotAuthorized component

This is a specific problem that happens when user is logged in, but does not have rights to use some resource. In this case  template of AuthorizeRouteView is not handling 401, like it does when user is not logged in.

Any thoughts?